# Naming standards for custom frameworks in maven

Tags: maven, package, maven-2, naming-conventions, standards

I am working on naming standards for package name, group and artifacts.

We have multiple departments/groups, engineering,testing, research and so on.

We also have some common frameworks we use across the groups and also some custom frameworks specifically for each of the departments.

For eg, One such custom framework is a custom caching framework to be used within engineering group.

I want to know what would be the standards for naming the package, group and artifacts for the caching framework.

Can I have it as below,

```
Group Id    : com.company.engineering.framework
Artifact Id : caching-framework
Package Name: com.company.engineering.framework.caching
```

Is this correct approach.

Also,I have a custom common framework which can be used across all groups.

So, can I have the naming as below,

```
Group Id    : com.company.framework
Artifact Id : common-framework
Package Name: com.company.framework.common
```

Not sure, I this is correct.

Can someone please help me out on this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible and sensible approach. What you should absolutely stick is to start all groupIds with your company domain, start all packages with the groupId (+ something) and only use lower case letters for the artifactId.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I only have the concern on if the package name should match the artifact name.

Comment: If you start your packaging with groupId.artifactId, you make sure that you do not accidentally define two classes in different artifacts which share the same fully qualified name. But there are of course other naming schemes which make sure that you do not have the same package name in different artifacts (which should be avoided, in my opinion)